# automatic download and install of iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect, itunes, iphone-developer-program

I have a list of ~100 apps that I need to download from the iTunes app store and install on an iOS device or iOS simulator. I'm trying to automate the process for a bunch of different testers.

They're not my apps. I don't have the source code. They are 3rd party, free apps.

Is this possible?

I'm open to hacky/scripted approaches.

Are there any legal issues here?

Comment: Have you tried iOS Device Management? https://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/management.html

Comment: Any chance these are YOUR apps?  It'd probably be a lot easier to automate Xcode than the App Store.

Comment: unfortunately they're not my apps, I do not have the source code. I'm talking about downloading public, free, 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no public API for automating those downloads for users. If you have all copy of those apps in your computer, you can sync every device.